# Why in_array() is not working in this case? (array from file())

Tags: php

Why is this code not working?

I have test.txt it contains:

```
A
B
C
```

My PHP code is:

```
$arr = file('test.txt');

if (in_array('A', $arr)) {
   echo 'A is found';
}
```

Result. nothing. But this following code works fine:

```
if (in_array('C', $arr)) {
    echo 'C is found';
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: My guess is line breaks. Try example #2 from http://php.net/trim

Comment: What does the loaded array look like when you print_r or var_dump it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `file()` will *not* remove the newline symbols from the end of each line, if you don't  tell him to do so

```
$arr = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

or remove it yourself, what will remove any other whitespace from the beginning and end of each line

```
$array = array_map('trim', file('test.txt'));
```

Comment: Ok I am a noob, this was so quick and fixed all my issues for now. Thanks